# How to send a local query to an open query DB2400 ? SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, db2-400

I need to retrieve data from a DB2 / 400 using open query in sql but with data to use in join. Why?

Right now my stored procedure does this to sum it up

```
SELECT *
FROM
(  
  SELECT 
        O.Column1 + P.Days TotalDays
    FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM myTable') O
    INNER JOIN myLocal Table L 
    ON L.Id = O.Id
    INNER JOIN Parameters P
    ON P.Id = O.Id
) T
WHERE T.TotalDays <> 0
```

this is just a quick example as you can see, I need to perform calculations using parameters from a local table. Pherhaps if i could send to linked server my parameters table and then join inside and perform calculations then filter it would be much faster?

Comment: You can't parametrise a Linked Server Query. For queries like this you're either going to need to pass the entire dataset to the linked server, and perform the match there, or retrieve the entire set and then match in the local instance. You can't have the RDBMS "work together" to complete a Join.

Comment: how can i pass the entire dataset to there?

Comment: You can join on a four-part name `server.db.schema.table` to query a linked table directly, if the remote provider supports it. However, care should be taken because these queries can become very inefficient, as the optimizer cannot accurately estimate how many rows the join will produce and it will generally transfer all rows from remote to local, or local to remote, with only one of those directions doing what you want and no way to control it. You may end up needing to split queries with explicit use of temp tables.

Comment: i think i got my answer, i'm looking for passing a table variable to the open query using dynamic sql